# Bootstrap Collapsed Navbar Lags and Doesn't Work Properly on Phone

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

I released a website a month ago and the client wanted to do a mobile view for it so, thanks to the use of Bootstrap 2, I didn't need to do much work.

Site: http://xn--cckyb0g6b3dy34xoswct2a182s.com/ (it's a Japanese site, please do not be overwhelmed by the content)

But right now I'm facing a problem with the navbar collapse feature in mobile view. For starters, it collapsed properly, can be expanded (although there is some major lag) and first-level items are also accessible but second level items are not.

Even stranger: when I resize my window on PC, it works fine. On my Xperia it works as I explained above

I've looked at the code and everything seems normal compared to the Bootstrap 2 implementations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your bootstrap.js. file(or min), find the substring

"ontouchstart"

and replace it with

"disable-ontouchstart"

Comment: Awesome, this works like a charm! Though the lag is still present, maybe too many submenus in one navigation bar